# How to get rid of duplicates in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm building a social graph from a list of tuples 'friends' like this:

```
(4118181 {'last_name': 'Belousov', 'first_name': 'Mikhail'})
```

Here's the function:

```
def addToGraph (g, start, friends):
    g.add_nodes_from(friends)
    egdes_to_add = [(start, entry[0]) for entry in friends]
    g.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)
    return g
```

As a result I get a graph with duplicated amount of nodes, the 1st with attributes, coming from

```
g.add_nodes_from(friends)
```

and the second is from

```
 g.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)
```

I read the docs, but can't figure out, how can I add both nodes with attributes and edges between those nodes?

Comment: Can you post what the nodes and edges look like (`g.nodes(data=True)` and `g.edges(data=True)`)?

Comment: Half of nodes: `((175472863, 'Bulenok', 'Olga'), {})`,
Another half, empty duplicates: `('175472863', {})`

Comment: And edges: `('4118181', '340559596', {})`

Comment: What is `start`, a node id? How do you call the function?

Comment: start is an id number of a person, whose social connections I'm researching, start and entry[0]  both are nodes, actually,  this function is used to build a global graph of friends, friends of friends etc.

Comment: Your edges are given as strings and your nodes are given as integers.  This is the source of your problem.  You need to convert `edges_to_add` to have integers.

Answer (score 1):

Your nodes are integers.  Your edges are strings.  When you add the nodes, it adds a bunch of nodes whose names are integers.  When it adds an edge, it sees a new edge between the strings `'4118181'`and `'340559596'`.  Python sees those as distinct from the integers, so it creates new nodes with the new names and puts an edge between them.

To fix this, you'll need to convert the strings to integers before adding the edges.

Answer (score 0):

So your function adds edges between the node `start` and every node in `friends`. I tried your code and I don't get any duplicate nodes. Here is my full example (note that I corrected a couple of errors in your code).

```
import networkx as nx

friends = [
    (4118181, {'last_name': 'Belousov', 'first_name': 'Mikhail'}),
    (1111111, {'last_name': 'A', 'first_name': 'B'}),
    (2222222, {'last_name': 'C', 'first_name': 'D'}),
    (3333333, {'last_name': 'E', 'first_name': 'F'})
]

def addToGraph(g, start, friends):
    g.add_nodes_from(friends)
    edges_to_add = [(start, entry[0]) for entry in friends]
    g.add_edges_from(edges_to_add)

G = nx.Graph()
addToGraph(G, 4118181, friends)

print('Nodes:', G.nodes())
print('Edges:', G.edges())
```

Output:

```
Nodes: [3333333, 4118181, 2222222, 1111111]
Edges: [(3333333, 4118181), (4118181, 4118181), (4118181, 2222222), (4118181, 1111111)]
```